# AWK conditional state inside for loop return more results than expected

Tags: bash, matrix, awk

Hello everyone I am trying to make a matrix that prints an element if it meets the condition and if it does not meet it, print a character.
The files are as follows:
names.txt

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
name6
name7
```

nthits.txt

```
name1 1 hits found
name2 2 hits found
name3 2 hits found
name4 4 hits found
name5 4 hits found
name6 2 hits found
name7 2 hits found
```

phits.txt

```
name7 1 hits found
```

The code I used was:

```
NAMES=$(cat names.txt)
for NAME in $NAMES; do
    HITS_NT=$(awk -F" " -v NAME=$NAME '{if ($1 == NAME) {print $2} else {print "0"}}' nthits.txt)
    HITS_AA=$(awk -F" " -v NAME=$NAME '{if ($1 == NAME) {print $2} else {print "0"}}' phits.txt)
    echo -e $NAME"\t"$HITS_NT"\t"$HITS_AA
done
```

The expected result would be this

```
name1   1   0
name2   2   0
name3   2   0
name4   4   0
name5   4   0
name6   2   0
name7   2   1
```

But when executing it, it prints more characters than expected.

```
name1   1 0 0 0 0 0 0   0
name2   0 2 0 0 0 0 0   0
name3   0 0 2 0 0 0 0   0
name4   0 0 0 4 0 0 0   0
name5   0 0 0 0 4 0 0   0
name6   0 0 0 0 0 2 0   0
name7   0 0 0 0 0 0 2   1
```

Any advice or suggestions?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Without the input files (nthits.txt and phits.txt), it is hard to tell why you get the wrong output. Please post excerpts of these files or you can make up some test contents if the original contents are sensitive.

Comment: Run the `awk` command on nthits.txt manually, and look at the output. It'll print a series of numbers, matching what you see in the printout. If you only want it to print the one matching entry, you need to modify it to do that. BTW, when debugging shells scripts, adding the command `set -x` at the beginning will get you an execution trace, showing what's happening as the script runs. Also, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes (e.g. you have a number of unquoted variable references).

Comment: ready @HaiVu, thanks.

Comment: Of course @GordonDavisson, when I run awk command it runs correctly. Thanks for your suggestions, I will check the link.

Comment: Why are you using `else { print "0" }` if you don't want all those zeroes? It prints a `0` for every line that doesn't match the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just do it in one `awk` call.

```
$: awk 'FILENAME == "names.txt" { print $0 "\t" lookup["nthits.txt"$0]+0 "\t" lookup["phits.txt"$0]+0 }
        { lookup[ FILENAME $1 ]=$2 }' nthits.txt phits.txt names.txt
name1   1   0
name2   2   0
name3   2   0
name4   4   0
name5   4   0
name6   2   0
name7   2   1
```

Second, try to avoid reading files with a `for` loop. This construct:

```
NAMES=$(cat names.txt)
for NAME in $NAMES; do
```

is error prone. If using `bash`, try something like this:

```
while read -r name; do
  # . . . 
done < names.txt
```

`awk` is the better tool for this, but to do the same thing in a pure `bash`     script, eliminate the `awk` entirely, because the repeated subprocess spawning actually slows it down.

```
declare -A nthits phits
while read -r name hits _; do nthits[$name]=$hits; done < nthits.txt
while read -r name hits _; do phits[$name]=$hits;  done < phits.txt
while read -r name; do
  printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$name" "${nthits[$name]:=0}" "${phits[$name]:=0}"
done < names.txt
```

The extra fields in your output are because you are multiprocessing every line. You are walking through each name in names.txt, and for every one, creating output for every line of both nthits.txt and phits.txt. As those files get larger (more records), you should notice a corresponding growth of columns in your output. To do what you were trying to do, you should select in each call to awk for only the current name in the loop.

To do that, you should have used

```
awk -v name=$NAME '$1 == name {print $2}' nthits.txt
```

which would have still read every line, but generated no output for those that don't match. This would still not produce a 0 if there were no matches, so you'd have needed something like

```
awk -v name=$NAME 'BEGIN{ out=0 } $1 == name { out=$2 } END{ print out }' nthits.txt
```

and you'd still have had to print the name and the tabs...
For all that, easier to just do everything inside `awk` as at the top. :)

Comment: For reference, [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is awesome.